# ¿Como identificar el tipo de lenguaje: C o C++ usando un preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c

Como dice el titulo:

> ¿Como identificar el tipo de lenguaje: C o C++ usando un preprocessor?

Estoy haciendo un archivo de recurso. Llamado `ids.h` que pienso usarlo en programas tanto para C, como para C++. La idea consiste en que si es C se compila una estructura, pero si es C++ se compila una clase:

```
#ifdef _C_
typedef struct{/***@param Code*/}Cadena;
#elif _CPP_
class Cadena{
/**@param Code*/
};

#endif
```

El objetivo es identificar el lenguaje para que no ocurra errores al momento de ejecutarlo.

Comment: Intenta usar la constante [__cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

Comment: Muchas gracias esa era la respuesta que esperaba. @MrDave1999 Parece interesante las instrucciones que el preprocesador le puede dar al compilador. Y por ultimo creo que me equivoqué en la pregunta.

Comment: Lo unico que lo reconoció fué `cpp` de `MinGW` . Pero al ejecutar el ejecutable no funciona. @MrDave1999

Comment: La constante `__cplusplus` es evaluada en la precompilación. Que no funciona?

Comment: @MrDave1999 Disculpe pero el error fué mio. Escribí: _cplusplus, cuando era __cplusplus. La diferencia es que la primera tiene solo uno de ""_ y por eso el compilador me daba error y la segunda tiene dos de "_ _". Fué un error ortografico lo que confundió al compilador dando un error. Me dí cuenta a ver la notificación que enseña asi: _ _ cplusplus. Gracias por la respuesta ahora sí funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás compilando en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), la macro `__cplusplus` estará definida, conteniendo el número de estándar de C++ soportado por el compilador:

- `199711L` antes de C++11.
- `201103L` C++11.

- `201402L` C++14.
- `201703L` C++17.
- `202002L` C++20.

Esto no sólo te permite saber si estás compilando en C++, además te permite tomar decisiones en base al estándar usado.